# C++/CLI template wrapper round

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++-cli

I have a set of multiple C++ classes that have the same interface (not derived from each other though).  I'm trying to wrap these to make them available in .NET.

I currently have a method that defines the wrapper class using C/C++ #defines and then I can subsequently instantiate classes with a simple line of code

However I can't debug this.  Ideally I would like to be able to use a generic or a template.  However I can't use a C++ type inside a generic which would be the ultimate way to solve this problem.

Has anyone any idea of how I can do this without using the dreaded macros?

***EDIT***:

OK Here is an example of the templated class I have written:

```
       template< typename CPPResamplerClass >
        ref class TResampler
        {
            CPPResamplerClass*  pResampler;
        public:

            TResampler( int inputSampleRate, int outputSampleRate, int bufferLen ) :
                pResampler( new CPPResamplerClass( inputSampleRate, outputSampleRate, bufferLen ) )
            {

            }

            ~TResampler()
            {
                this->!ResamplerName();
            }

            !TResampler()
            {
                if (pResampler)
                {
                    delete pResampler;
                    pResampler = nullptr;
                }
            }

            property int HistorySize
            {
                int get()
                {
                    return pResampler->HistorySize();
                }
            }

            array< float >^ ResampleAudio(array< float >^ in)
            {
                pResampler->Get
                    array< float >^ out = gcnew array< float >(in->Length);
                cli::pin_ptr< float > pIn = &in[0];
                cli::pin_ptr< float > pOut = &out[0];

                unsigned int inLen = in->Length;
                unsigned int outLen = out->Length;

                if (pResampler->ResampleAudio(pOut, outLen, pIn, inLen))
                {
                    System::Array::Resize(out, outLen);
                    return out;
                }
                return nullptr;
            }
        };

        typedef TResampler< ::Vec::SpeexResample >  SpeexResample;
```

I then want to access this from C# however `SpeexResample` does not exist.  This could well be because I am using a typedef ...

Comment: This question *definitely* needs some example code. As a high rep user you should know what a [mcve] is...

Comment: Templates are a C++ detail and are of no use to any other .NET language.  Use the `generic` keyword instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: But I can't use a C++ type as a parameter to a generic class ... can I?  If I can .. can you explain how, as thats the crux of my problem! ;)

Comment: You can use the factory pattern and call your C++ template class via a cls-compliant interface class.

Comment: Hmya, the core problem here is that your code is simply not generic.  There is nothing meaningful you can do when the C# code asks for a `TResampler<int>` or `TResampler`<string>`.  And another million types.  You'll have to slog it out and only expose the ones that can be meaningfully used.  Should be a reasonably short list.

Comment: @HansPassant:  So there is no easy way of aliasing ResamplerInt or ResamplerString?  That would be ideal ... but I can't seem to find anything like a typedef in .NET :(

Answer (score 2):

Templates don't exist until they're instantiated. While you could instantiate one explicitly:

```cpp
template ref class TResampler<SomeNativeClass>;
```

It wouldn't be exactly user-friendly to use from C#. The exported type will *literally* have angle brackets in its name. Good luck using *that*. In C# it's only doable through reflection.

The next best thing is to use derived types. Here's a minimal example:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace CppCli {

    class NativeClassA
    {
        int foo;

    public:
        NativeClassA(int foo) : foo(foo) { std::cout << "Built native class A" << std::endl; }
        int getFoo() const { return foo; }
    };

    class NativeClassB
    {
        int foo;

    public:
        NativeClassB(int foo) : foo(foo) { std::cout << "Built native class B" << std::endl; }
        int getFoo() const { return foo; }
    };

    template<typename NativeClass>
    public ref class ManagedWrapper
    {
        NativeClass* ptr;

    public:
        ManagedWrapper(int foo)
            : ptr(new NativeClass(foo))
        {}

        ~ManagedWrapper()
        {
            this->!ManagedWrapper();
        }

        !ManagedWrapper()
        {
            if (ptr)
            {
                delete ptr;
                ptr = nullptr;
            }
        }

        property int Foo { int get() { return ptr->getFoo(); } }
    };

    public ref class ManagedWrapperA : ManagedWrapper<NativeClassA>
    {
    public:
        ManagedWrapperA(int foo) : ManagedWrapper(foo) {}
    };

    public ref class ManagedWrapperB : ManagedWrapper<NativeClassB>
    {
    public:
        ManagedWrapperB(int foo) : ManagedWrapper(foo) {}
    };

};
```

Sure enough, `ManagedWrapperA` and `ManagedWrapperB` are visible from C#. Maybe you could macro *these* definitions and still get a decent debugging experience.

Comment: Thanks for this response I hadn't spotted it arrive and was working on something else.  I will have a look at if I can get this working.  At present it gives me a compiler stack overflow but it looks promising.