# Function templates in C++/CLI

Tags: templates, namespaces, c++-cli

I am trying to write some function templates in a namespace in a C++/CLI like this:

```
// header file
namespace MyCLI {
    namespace MyFunctions {
        template <typename T>
        double sum(T a, T b) {
            return (double) a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is that when I compile the project into a dll and try to use it the namespace MyFunctions does not show up. I think that is happening because I have not explicitly instantiated my template for all the types I would need, so I add the following at the bottom of the header file:

```
extern template double MyCLI::MyFunctions::sum<double>(double,double);
```

But this still does not give me access to the function `sum` for `double` type. My suspicion is that since the project is compiled into managed code this is following the rules of C# that you cannot have functions without a class. So next I tried to make a class inside the namespace MyCLI and make `sum` a static member of the class like this:

```
// header file
namespace MyCLI {

    public ref class MyFunctions
    {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        static double sum(T a, T b) {
            return (double) a + b;
        }
    };
}

extern template double MyCLI::MyFunctions::sum<double>(double,double);
```

Now when I use the assembly I can see the `MyFunctions` class in `MyCLI` but I still cannot access the `sum` function from the class.

I would be very thankful if someone could give me any pointers on how to solve this problem, or why am I facing this issue in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the correct syntax to explicitly instantiate a template. You need to drop the `extern` keyword and put the instantiation in a cpp file (not in a header) so it's defined only once. You were unable to see the method because it *didn't exist* due to lack of template instantiation. Templates are *not* generics, they look similar but are very different. Templates are *instantiated* at compile time, whereas generics are *reified* at runtime.

But if you plan on using this code from a different .NET language you're out of luck: the method will *literally* contain angle brackets in its name, so you'll have a hard time using it without breaking the language's naming rules. You could use reflection but I'm sure it's not what you intended.

For this simple case, you could simply write several overloads (without using templates at all), it's the simplest thing to do. If you want more fancy stuff, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534610/3764814) for inspiration.